# List of Domain Names for Google Geocoding API

Tags: api, google-maps, geocoding, domain-name

We are trying to use Google Geocoding API in one of the system to find the co-ordinates of a particular address.
Google API call will be made from an PL/SQL API. We have done the necessary configuration @DB level i.e., ACL and wallets.
But need to know the list of google domain names so that we can get them configured in our firewall.
Customer Registration with Google is in progress but we need to know the details of domain to prepare the environment for implementing the solution.
Even few domain names for countries like UK,Greece and Spain would help us to start up with.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> The Geocoding API, Directions API, Elevation API, Distance Matrix API, and the Static Maps API use:
>
> Over HTTP:
>
> - maps.google.com (legacy)
> - maps.googleapis.com (recommended)
>
> Over HTTPS:
>
> - maps-api-ssl.google.com (legacy)
> - maps.googleapis.com (recommended)

This information is available in Google Cloud support portal. I just copied it from there.